# Xquery "replace bitmask value for given index" issue in Oracle Service Bus

Tags: replace, xquery, middleware, bitmask, osb

I'm trying to replace a 32 bit string variable. At first, all values "0".

```
$bitmask:="00000000000000000000000000000000"
```

I have some index values and should replace the values in these indexes with "1".

For instance, I have index values=(3,10)

expected result should be;

```
$bitmask:="00100000010000000000000000000000"
```

Actually I did it :) but there is space characters in my bitmask values. I couldn't remove the space characters.

My working code;

```
$serviceBits :=  tokenize('0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0',',')

<services>
{
for $t at $pos in $serviceBits
let  $temp := ''
return 
 if($pos = data($myElement/ns:position)) then
   concat($temp, '1')
 else  
   replace(concat($temp, $t)," ","")    
}
</services>
```

And the result of my working code is;

```
<services>0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0</services>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you post a sequence into the newly constructed element, which gets serialized with spaces in between. Explicitly use `string-join` here:

```
<services>{
  string-join(
    (: all the other code for modification :),
    '' (: Nothing between the individual strings :)
  )
}</services>
```

Anyway, I'm not sure where your call on `tokenize` and `$bitmap` are connected.

For converting an array to a sequence, adjusting some values and returning the string again, use `string-to-codepoints` respective the reverse function. It returns unicode codepoints, to change from 0 to 1 just add 1. An example:

```
let $bitmask := '00000000000000000000000000000000'
return
  codepoints-to-string(
    for $char at $i in string-to-codepoints($bitmask)
    return
      if ($i = (3,10))
        then $char + 1
        else $char
  )
```